# Control panel not working in IE 9 & 10

Tags: control-panel, javascript

I am using EE v2.5.5 and the control panel doesn't work properly in IE 9 and 10. The issue seems to be that EE doesn't know you are logged in when a script is requested and so instead of returning the JS you just get the login screen instead. SO the URL below for example:

```
http://www.showsec.co.uk/admin.php?S=24384227da408225ee16a159edfba4966ac36622&D=cp&C=javascript&M=load&file=css&theme=default&v=1369159495
```

Just returns the login page even though I am logged in

In fact if I login to the control panel in IE 9 or 10 and then open a new tab and go to the control panel URL I just get the login screen again. The browser has forgotten I am logged in already!

Answer (score 1):

The control panel of EE 2.5.5 certainly works with IE 9. I have a client using it right now. This would indicate your problem lies elsewhere.

Do you have peculiar settings for handling cookies in your browser?

You could try switching your control panel session type in Admin->Security and Sessions. Also check whether you have anything set up in Cookie Settings under the same menu.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this could be cookie issue. If you have Firefox with Firebug, or something similar, check the domain in the cookies that are being sent from the server. The last time I had a problem like this the cookie domain didn't exactly match the domain in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the cause was but I found a solution. In system/expressionengine/libraries/core.php on line 467 change the following line:

```
$this->EE->functions->redirect(BASE.AMP.'C=login'.$return_url);
```

To be this:

```
// this if statement is a hack to prevent auth issues in IE when requesting JS and CSS files
if($this->EE->router->fetch_class()!=='javascript' && $this->EE->router->fetch_class()!=='css') {
    $this->EE->functions->redirect(BASE.AMP.'C=login'.$return_url);
}
```